# Woocommerce coupons add_discount error when using that function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, coupon

I'm having issues adding coupon discounts via code. I'm getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_discount() on a non-object
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teachingyounet\wp-content\themes\responsive\functions.php
>   on line 43

My code:

```
function zkr_add_discount(){
    global $woocommerce;
    global $total_weight;

    if (current_user_can('distributor') || current_user_can('administrator')) {
        //do stuff for administrator roles
        wp_get_current_user();

        //$coupon = $current_user->cimy_uef_COUPON;
        $coupon = get_the_author_meta( 'cimy_uef_COUPON', $current_user->ID );
        //$wc = new  WC_Cart;
        //print_r($wc->coupons_enabled());die;
        //if($wc->coupons_enabled())
        /*$code = $coupon;
            $the_coupon = new WC_Coupon( $code );*/
        //$wc->add_discount('testcoupon'); //sanitize_text_field( $coupon )

        if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount( sanitize_text_field( $coupon ))){
            $woocommerce->show_messages();
        }


    }
}
```

I thought I had the answer but I was wrong :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you call add_discount before the cart has been initialized?
Try to use:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'zkr_add_discount' );
```

in your functions.php

Comment: No that does not work, tried it just now. There must be some other action hook I need to use or something.